# Static Int not start at 0

Tags: c#

```
public partial class MainBookingform : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    static int numberOfBeachBookingInteger = 0;
    static int numberOfBushBookingInteger = 0;
    static int totalRevenueInteger = 0;


  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
            {
                numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
                beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();
            }
            if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
            {
                numberOfBushBookingInteger += 1;
                bushBachLabel.Text = numberOfBushBookingInteger.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hi, I would like to see these integer to start at "0" when I debug the program. however, these label which I assign to those integers always start at '1'

please help!

Comment: You are incrementing them before assigning their values to a label, what did you think would happen?

Comment: of course they do. you increase by 1! numberOfBushBookingInteger += 1;

Comment: Should the two ifs have the same condition?

Answer (score 5):

Before you write the numbers to a label, you always  increment them:

```
numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
```

So of course the value in the labels is never 0.

Answer (score 3):

switch the order of these lines

```
numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();
```

you're increasing it before you display it.  What you want is :

```
if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
{
    beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();
    numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
}
if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
{
    bushBachLabel.Text = numberOfBushBookingInteger.ToString();
    numberOfBushBookingInteger += 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware that static variables are shared across all sessions in one ASP.NET process?  Meaning that if two users hit the site they will *both* increment the static variables (they would not necessarily be consecutive for each user)?

That said, you *could try* just incrementing the value *after* creating the label:

```
if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
{
    bushBachLabel.Text = numberOfBushBookingInteger.ToString();
    numberOfBushBookingInteger += 1;
}
```

Comment: word up.  Don't use static variables they're terrifying in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you're already adding `1` before the integers are first displayed.

```
numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();
```

You could define your integers as `-1` and they should be displayed as `0`.

```
static int numberOfBeachBookingInteger = -1;
static int numberOfBushBookingInteger = -1;
```

Alternatively, turning around your logic to

```
beachBachLabel.Text = numberOfBeachBookingInteger.ToString();
numberOfBeachBookingInteger += 1;
```

brings the desired effect, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Session["beachBach"] != null)
{
  beachBachLabel.Text = (numberOfBeachBookingInteger++).ToString();
}
```